# Is there a way to place the .github/.gitlab folders in a custom path inside my project?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I'm working on a project that has multiple setup files and folders that are placed on the root of the Git project. What I'm trying to achieve is to organize them inside a folder that will be placed on the root of the project and then contain a single file on the root of the project like `.gitconfig` that will point to the paths of those folders, so Github or Gitlab for example will be able to find the appropriate folders.

From a research I did online, I couldn't find anything related to my issue. However, I believe that there should exist a way to achieve this because on large projects with multiple environments, setup files and people working on it the root folder of the Git project will be a chaos.

Comment: Can you please add details: which setup files are those (.gitlab-ci.yml, templates, ...) and what are trying to achieve (for example, do you want to load different files based on some condition)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That does not seem to be supported.

For instance, GitHub Actions include workflows, which, as [the documentation mentions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/about-workflows), must be in a `.github/workflows` directory in the root folder of the repository, and a GitHub Action will not read anything else to get the path of its actions.

Same idea for a [`.gitlab-ci.yml`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/gitlab_ci_yaml.html), which must be in the root of your repository, although it can [*include* other yml pipeline definition](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html).